# Recognizing a blank in an R conditional statement

Tags: r

I have a massive database and am trying to efficiently add a new calculated column, conditional on the status of another. Assume for example I have 3 columns in my df.

If col 1 is not empty, then I want to apply the formula (df$col3*df$col1^df$col2).
If col 1 is empty, then I want the new column to have the value of df$col3.
I tried

```
df$col4<-ifelse(df$col1 == "", (df$col3 * df$col1 ^ df$col2), df$col3)
```

but the issue I'm running in to is this does not recognize the empty cells in df$col1. I also tried making df$col1==NA, but to not avail. 
How do I make my conditional statement recognize the empty cell in R, and respond accordingly?

Comment: I'm trying it now. Thank you for the suggestion. It's throwing an error I'm attempting to debug at the moment

Comment: can you show the error

Comment: "Error in match.arg(which) : 'arg' must be NULL or a character vector"
I'm also looking to see if there's a blank. not seeing it there                                            > unique(df$col1)
 [1] NA  5  3  1  6  2 10  8  7  4  9

Comment: yes, with blank, it owuld be characterr.  Can  you try `ifelse(trimws(df$col1) == "", (df$col3 * as.numeric(df$col1) ^ df$col2), df$col3)`

Comment: I see some `NA`.  IN that case, could you do `ifelse(is.na(df$col1),  (df$col3 * df$col1 ^ df$col2), df$col3)`

Comment: same result on both. it's calculating col4 properly where col1 is numeric, but giving an NA when it's NA

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211578/discussion-between-jesse001-and-akrun).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be that there are spaces instead of blank.  An option is to wrap with `trimws` to remove the spaces on 'col1', and then apply the `ifelse`

```
ifelse(trimws(df$col1) != "", (df$col3 * as.numeric(df$col1) ^ df$col2), df$col3)
```

If the column 'col1' is `numeric` and have `NA` elements, use the standard `is.na` to check for `NA` elements

```
ifelse(!is.na(df$col1), (df$col3 * df$col1 ^ df$col2), df$col3)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you've got a large database you might consider a data.table to improve efficiency in assignment. Here I assign col3 to col4, then sub assign the derived value to those that are not NA in col1 by "chaining" two expressions

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df[, col4 := col3][!is.na(col1), col4 := col3 * col1 ^ col2]
```